# Threadx "tx_timer_id"

Tags: timer, threadx

I`m using Threadx, and I have two timers with the same "tx_timer_id"

Is that legal? I`m having issues with one of these timers and was wondering if this is an indication of the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert, but from what I can see, tx_timer_id is always 0x4154494D.
Please elaborate on the actual issue you see.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal. ThreadX built in error-checking version will check if this field is equal to 0x4154494DUL ('ATIM') and return TX_TIMER_ERROR if it's not.